# how to create .ASPXAUTH cookie on python

Tags: python, http-headers

i need to create .ASPXAUTH cookie on python. i programing to desktop client. and first request not need .ASPXAUTH cookie but second request is need.

My First Request Headers:

```
User-Agent: WebPolicy
Host: xxx.host
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

My First Response Headers:

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: private

header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked

header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

header: Set-Cookie: tivi_=3tnihi55ezuk50zyrrpuwv45; path=/; HttpOnly

header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727

header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

header: Date: Thu, 14 Oct 2010 13:05:50 GMT
```

And i need second send headers :

```
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 259
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IMiddlewareServices/Login"
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Host: mw.webtv.ttnet.com.tr
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=090F2718E32AF3F9B1C9E5A15BA54CFD8D4430C44A91029719953D4A6D38DD1D9164D86D772E2645C0C0545A71C12EA80AE5A8F725FD6037BD00DB291A863DD577735E16D8745E2833979F337935F29A37C509FB0350F1180DA0D2C1C44F97D0F081B13D33984C198ECD695C34B2E79A3E7CFBDD2D67D630C019714C3A70280E; tivi_=nqkngs45drnsh4z4y4b30g55
```

please help me! how to create ".ASPXAUTH" cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

Python requests module does the job for me with **.ASPXAUTH** cookie-based authentication. In a simple example below **.ASPXAUTH** cookie is received after the first **session.get** call and used for the second call:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.get('https://host/user/login?username=###&password=###')
print session.cookies
session.get('https://host/apicall')
print session.cookies
```