# Emulate ASP.NET Session with Keys Using Alternate Stack

Tags: asp.net, session

### Update 2

I was able to find some useful information by looking through the .NET source code, but ultimately it seems like it will take too long to reverse engineer for the deadline I have, so I have opted to use the first option of just having a web service produce the .ASPXAUTH cookie for me. I have found a couple more useful links below in case anyone wants to look more into generating their own cookie from scratch. Thanks to everyone who replied!

#### Links

- [Code Project Explanation of Forms Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16822/The-Anatomy-of-Forms-Authentication)
- [Picture of Forms Authentication Ticket Bitmap](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Forms_Auth_Internals/image001.jpg)

### Update 1

I was able to find the source from [.netlibrarysource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx). Looks like the source code for setauthcookie is included in this source code. I will see if I can figure out how to generate the cookie from looking at it.

### Original Post

I saw another thread [1] with a potentially similar question, but I can't tell from the wording exactly what the poster wants, so I am writing my own.

I have a web application that is written in ASP.NET and another language/stack (we'll say RoR) being introduced to do a facelift on some of the functionality of the site. Since .NET was first, all the session precedence revolves around using an authentication ticket (ASPXAUTH field in the cookie) to verify whether a user was authenticated. This field is generated in many ASP sites to handle sessioning, and I can't get around by *not* using it.

This normally wouldn't be a problem, but I want the user to be able to log into the site using RoR pages and be able to preserve the authentication state across the site regardless of whether they are visiting ASPX pages or RoR pages. So, I feel like I have two options:

1. Create some .NET webservice that RoR makes a request to in order to generate the appropriate token (ASPXAUTH data for the cookie) from the machinekey [2] using SetAuthCookie(), or
2. Find a way for RoR to emulate whatever method .NET uses to generate the token, so I can set the value in the cookie and not have to reauthenticate the user when they visit an ASPX page.

Number 2 is preferable, but I can't find anything on how to do so after searching on Google for 3-4 hours, so does anyone here now how to accomplish number 2? Otherwise, I will do the former or try something else. Thanks in advance for suggestions, comments, or alternate options I'm not yet considering.

[1] [how to create .ASPXAUTH cookie on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933419/how-to-create-aspxauth-cookie-on-python)
[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Comment: I doubt [1] would help as he didn't get an answer in 2 years!

Comment: I've made a custom authentication provider for an MVC project at my work which uses SetAuthCookie; I'll see if I can give you the source code when I'm back at work.

Comment: Thanks, @RussC! I just updated my findings. I think I am going to use a .NET webservice for login/registration that will be called by the alternate stack. I figure I will also generate the .ASPXAUTH session in that webservice and pass it back in the response. Would be good to see code just in case I run into anything related.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET sets authorization cookie. You can also create your own security cookie which you can set along with ASP.NET cookie (just hijack login code). Then you can access this cookie to check if user is logged in.

Comment: But what if the first hit to the site is to a Ruby generated page ? there'd be no cookie.

Comment: You could create some web service (wcf preferably) which Ruby can access to pass authorization to .NET code.

Comment: @fenix2222, that was what number 1 is about. I may go that route, but I was trying to figure out if I could do number 2 instead (meaning setting the cookie at login entirely using RoR with no .NET).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer so please don't be too harsh but it's not a comment either so here goes:

How are you hosting the RoR content, are you using it under IIS or another way ?

What I would investigate if it's possible for both contents to run from the same Site/Virtual Directory in IIS and use Authentication via the Global ASP handlers and then pass the query through to the correct handler.

It is possible to make a generic handler that catches all traffic and you could implement your authentication that way; the mechanics of this depend on which version of IIs you're using and how your RoR content is served.

Comment: The RoR content will be on separate Unix servers under the same subdomain.